# I'm beginner at Node JS trying to searching into JSON array using basic for loop, for iterating over array but not getting the desired results

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to search into json array using basic for loop, but not getting expected results. Please check what I'm missing.

Searching into json and want to get desired results on the basis of key:

```js
json = [{
    "web_pages": [
      "https://www.iitbbs.ac.in/"
    ],
    "name": "IIT Bhubaneswar",
    "alpha_two_code": "IN",
    "state-province": "Odisha",
    "domains": [
      "iitbbs.ac.in"
    ],
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "http://www.davietjal.org/"
    ],
    "name": "DAV Institute of Engineering & Technology",
    "alpha_two_code": "IN",
    "state-province": "Punjab",
    "domains": [
      "davietjal.org"
    ],
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "https://www.sciencespo-rennes.fr/en/"
    ],
    "name": "Institut d'études politiques de Rennes",
    "alpha_two_code": "FR",
    "state-province": null,
    "domains": [
      "sciencespo-rennes.fr"
    ],
    "country": "France"
  }
]

let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  if (json[i] === "India") {
    console.log(json[i]);
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not tell us your origin story. Also take the [tour] if you haven't so you know how to respond to answers properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the place of this piece of data like `json[i].country`.

```js
json = [{
    "web_pages": [
      "https://www.iitbbs.ac.in/"
    ],
    "name": "IIT Bhubaneswar",
    "alpha_two_code": "IN",
    "state-province": "Odisha",
    "domains": [
      "iitbbs.ac.in"
    ],
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "http://www.davietjal.org/"
    ],
    "name": "DAV Institute of Engineering & Technology",
    "alpha_two_code": "IN",
    "state-province": "Punjab",
    "domains": [
      "davietjal.org"
    ],
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "https://www.sciencespo-rennes.fr/en/"
    ],
    "name": "Institut d'études politiques de Rennes",
    "alpha_two_code": "FR",
    "state-province": null,
    "domains": [
      "sciencespo-rennes.fr"
    ],
    "country": "France"
  }
]
let count = 0
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  if (json[i].country === "India") {
    console.log(json[i].name)
    count++
  }
}
console.log(count);
```